# Using Graph Cut algorithm

Tags: matlab, graph, computer-vision, vision

I want to use Graph Cut algorithm to label some Video Cubids. Here is my problem.

As far as I understand, GraphCut has an energy function being called `D` (cost per element), and a `V` pairwise that is cost of two adjacent naighbours. Now, I have processed video and I have some idea to what to set as `V` (like euclidean distance) , but I have no idea what I could use for energy function `D`. It should be noted, I don't have train data, so I am not be able to compare input data to a model or foreknown distribution to obtain `D`.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you need `D(l,s)` to be related to how likely it is for the site `s` to have the label `l`. How to model that and what are acceptable things to use for `D` spans many research areas. For example there are many papers that study reasonable `D`'s for stereo, segmentation, denoising, etc. A good reference to understand these issues would be [the original Veksler, Boykov, Zabih](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/faculty/olga/Papers/cvpr98.pdf) paper. Once you understand this basic paper you can read more sophisticated works related to how to user Graphcuts applied to the particular problem you want to solve.